# List group plan gitlab api

Tags: node.js, gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm allowing GitLab users to add my integration to their Groups.

My service need to subscribe to the Groups webhooks, but on a free tier Groups webhooks are not enable so I want to subscribe to Project hooks in that case.

My question: Is there any way to look at a group plan? To know if he is on a free or a paid/trial tier?

So far I've looked at the Licence API (which is only for self managed) and the Group api. I'm surprised [this endpoint: GET /groups/:id](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#details-of-a-group) isn't providing this information.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With administrator credentials (self-managed only) you can use the [license endpoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/license.html) to get the default plan for the instance, as you mentioned in your question.

Without an admin token, this is somewhat harder.

On gitlab.com, you can also use the [namespaces API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/namespaces.html) to get plan information for a particular namespace. You'll see a `plan` field in the response. For example:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "name": "mynamespace",
    "plan": "silver",
    ...
  }
]
```

There are [several values](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/e8440ef942d32757d06e9727f8a7189a274f8531/ee/app/models/ee/plan.rb#L9-17) that can possibly come back for `plan`. If it says `default`, that means no subscription is applied to the namespace and has the default plan for the instance -- this will likely be the case for all namespaces in a self-managed gitlab instance.

If you don't have admin API access and need to figure out the subscription level of a self-managed instance, the next-best way you can handle this is to just try to use API endpoints that are exclusive to particular subscription levels to determine what features are available.

Comment: Thank you it helps. Sometimes there is no plan in the response, does that mean the user authenticated doesn't have the access to the plan type ?

Comment: @SydneyC. if I recall correctly, only owners can see plan information.